# Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-musicmanager

Tags: apt

I was writing a script to install `google-musicmanager` and in testing it, managed to add it twice to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-musicmanager.list` so the file now looks like this:

```
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/musicmanager/deb/ stable main
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/musicmanager/deb/ stable main
```

My question is what is the best way to fix this? Is it okay to just manually delete the duplicate line in the source list or will that break `apt`?

The code that added the line was

```
sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/musicmanager/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-musicmanager.list'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should delete the duplicate line in the file; that won't break `apt`.